# How to use argparse with gunicorn when deploying a flask app?

Tags: python, flask, deployment, pytorch, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a flask app that uses the argparse module to add arguments for a pytorch model that dictates particular options for how the model should run.

Everything runs fine locally however when trying to run my flask app with `gunicorn app:app` on a ubuntu ec2 instance it looks like in addition gunicorn is trying to parse the arguments thrown in by argparse from the flask app.

If I don't use gunicorn, I run my application as follows:

```
    Sudo Python app.py

     * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
     * Environment: production
       WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
       Use a production WSGI server instead.
     * Debug mode: off
     * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But if I try to run with gunicorn like this:

```
  Sudo gunicorn app:app
```

I get the following error :

```
usage: gunicorn [-h] [--name NAME] [--gpu_ids GPU_IDS]
                [--checkpoints_dir CHECKPOINTS_DIR] [--model MODEL]
                [--norm NORM] [--use_dropout] [--data_type {8,16,32}]
                [--verbose] [--fp16] [--local_rank LOCAL_RANK]
                [--batchSize BATCHSIZE] [--loadSize LOADSIZE]
                [--fineSize FINESIZE] [--label_nc LABEL_NC]
                [--input_nc INPUT_NC] [--output_nc OUTPUT_NC]
                [--resize_or_crop RESIZE_OR_CROP] [--serial_batches]
                [--no_flip] [--nThreads NTHREADS]
                [--max_dataset_size MAX_DATASET_SIZE]
                [--display_winsize DISPLAY_WINSIZE] [--tf_log] [--netG NETG]
                [--ngf NGF] [--n_downsample_global N_DOWNSAMPLE_GLOBAL]
                [--n_blocks_global N_BLOCKS_GLOBAL]
                [--n_blocks_local N_BLOCKS_LOCAL]
                [--n_local_enhancers N_LOCAL_ENHANCERS]
                [--niter_fix_global NITER_FIX_GLOBAL] [--no_instance]
                [--instance_feat] [--label_feat] [--feat_num FEAT_NUM]
                [--load_features] [--n_downsample_E N_DOWNSAMPLE_E]
                [--nef NEF] [--n_clusters N_CLUSTERS] [--ntest NTEST]
                [--results_dir RESULTS_DIR] [--aspect_ratio ASPECT_RATIO]
                [--phase PHASE] [--which_epoch WHICH_EPOCH]
                [--how_many HOW_MANY] [--cluster_path CLUSTER_PATH]
                [--use_encoded_image] [--export_onnx EXPORT_ONNX]
                [--engine ENGINE] [--onnx ONNX]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: app:ap
```

Here is the flask app code:

```
opt = BaseOptions().parse(save=False)
opt.nThreads = 1   # test code only supports nThreads = 1
opt.batchSize = 1  # test code only supports batchSize = 1
opt.serial_batches = True  # no shuffle
opt.no_flip = True  # no flip


# Config
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'upload')
app.config['TEST_A'] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test_A')
app.config['RESULT_DIR'] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'results')
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'])

# Setup
if not os.path.exists(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR']):
    os.mkdir(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'])

if not os.path.exists(app.config['RESULT_DIR']):
    os.mkdir(app.config['RESULT_DIR'])

# Helpers
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
        filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

def error(msg):
    return jsonify({'error': msg})

# Routers
@app.route('/')
def pong():
    return 'Pong', {'Content-Type': 'text-plain; charset=utf-8'}


@app.route('/gen', methods=['POST'])
def gen():
    print("request.files", request.files)
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return error('file form-data not existed'), 412

    image = request.files['file']
    print("image", image)
    if not allowed_file(image.filename):
        return error('Only supported %s' % app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']), 415

    # Submit taylor.jpg ---> save image to upload/12345678/taylor.jpg (upload/timestamp/imagename.ext)
    t = int(time.time())

    image_dir = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], str(t))
    print("IMAGE DIR HELLO")
    print(image_dir)
    os.mkdir(image_dir)

    test_A_Dir = os.path.join(image_dir, 'test_A')
    image_path = os.path.join(test_A_Dir, image.filename) 

    print("image_dir", test_A_Dir)
    print("image_path", image_path)

    os.mkdir(test_A_Dir)
    new_image_path = os.path.join(test_A_Dir, image.filename)
    image.save(new_image_path)
    
    opt.dataroot = test_A_Dir
    data_loader = CreateDataLoader(opt)
    print(data_loader)
    dataset = data_loader.load_data()
    print(dataset)

    # test
    if not opt.engine and not opt.onnx:
        model = create_model(opt)
        if opt.data_type == 16:
            model.half()
        elif opt.data_type == 8:
            model.type(torch.uint8)
                
        if opt.verbose:
           
    else:
        from run_engine import run_trt_engine, run_onnx
        
    for i, data in enumerate(dataset):
        if i >= opt.how_many:
            break
        if opt.data_type == 16:
            data['label'] = data['label'].half()
            data['inst']  = data['inst'].half()
        elif opt.data_type == 8:
            data['label'] = data['label'].uint8()
            data['inst']  = data['inst'].uint8()
        if opt.export_onnx:
            print ("Exporting to ONNX: ", opt.export_onnx)
            assert opt.export_onnx.endswith("onnx"), "Export model file should end with .onnx"
            torch.onnx.export(model, [data['label'], data['inst']],
                            opt.export_onnx, verbose=True)
            exit(0)
        minibatch = 1 
        if opt.engine:
            generated = run_trt_engine(opt.engine, minibatch, [data['label'], data['inst']])
        elif opt.onnx:
            generated = run_onnx(opt.onnx, opt.data_type, minibatch, [data['label'], data['inst']])
        else:        
            generated = model.inference(data['label'], data['inst'], data['image'])
        t2 = int(time.time())
        # Convert image to numpy array
        fake =util.tensor2im(generated.data[0])    
        result_dir = os.path.join(app.config['RESULT_DIR'], str(t2))
        result_path = os.path.join(result_dir, image.filename)
        os.mkdir(result_dir)
        util.save_image(fake, result_path)
    return send_file(result_path,mimetype='image/jpeg',
    as_attachment=True,)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app.run()
```

Here is the file parsing the arguments :

```
class BaseOptions():
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        self.initialized = False

    def initialize(self):    
        # experiment specifics
        self.parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, default='caf_pix2pix', help='name of the experiment. It decides where to store samples and models')        
        self.parser.add_argument('--gpu_ids', type=str, default='-1', help='gpu ids: e.g. 0  0,1,2, 0,2. use -1 for CPU')
        self.parser.add_argument('--checkpoints_dir', type=str, default='./trained', help='models are saved here')
        self.parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, default='pix2pixHD', help='which model to use')
        self.parser.add_argument('--norm', type=str, default='instance', help='instance normalization or batch normalization')        
        self.parser.add_argument('--use_dropout', action='store_true', help='use dropout for the generator')
        self.parser.add_argument('--data_type', default=32, type=int, choices=[8, 16, 32], help="Supported data type i.e. 8, 16, 32 bit")
        self.parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true', default=False, help='toggles verbose')
        self.parser.add_argument('--fp16', action='store_true', default=False, help='train with AMP')
        self.parser.add_argument('--local_rank', type=int, default=0, help='local rank for distributed training')
       
        # input/output sizes       
        self.parser.add_argument('--batchSize', type=int, default=1, help='input batch size')
        self.parser.add_argument('--loadSize', type=int, default=1024, help='scale images to this size')
        self.parser.add_argument('--fineSize', type=int, default=512, help='then crop to this size')
        self.parser.add_argument('--label_nc', type=int, default= 0 , help='# of input label channels')
        self.parser.add_argument('--input_nc', type=int, default=3, help='# of input image channels')
        self.parser.add_argument('--output_nc', type=int, default=3, help='# of output image channels')

        # for setting inputs
        # self.parser.add_argument('--dataroot', type=str, default='./datasets/w/') 
        self.parser.add_argument('--resize_or_crop', type=str, default='scale_width', help='scaling and cropping of images at load time [resize_and_crop|crop|scale_width|scale_width_and_crop]')
        self.parser.add_argument('--serial_batches', action='store_true', help='if true, takes images in order to make batches, otherwise takes them randomly')        
        self.parser.add_argument('--no_flip', action='store_true', help='if specified, do not flip the images for data argumentation') 
        self.parser.add_argument('--nThreads', default=2, type=int, help='# threads for loading data')                
        self.parser.add_argument('--max_dataset_size', type=int, default=float("inf"), help='Maximum number of samples allowed per dataset. If the dataset directory contains more than max_dataset_size, only a subset is loaded.')

        # for displays
        self.parser.add_argument('--display_winsize', type=int, default=512,  help='display window size')
        self.parser.add_argument('--tf_log', action='store_true', help='if specified, use tensorboard logging. Requires tensorflow installed')

        # for generator
        self.parser.add_argument('--netG', type=str, default='global', help='selects model to use for netG')
        self.parser.add_argument('--ngf', type=int, default=64, help='# of gen filters in first conv layer')
        self.parser.add_argument('--n_downsample_global', type=int, default=4, help='number of downsampling layers in netG') 
        self.parser.add_argument('--n_blocks_global', type=int, default=9, help='number of residual blocks in the global generator network')
        self.parser.add_argument('--n_blocks_local', type=int, default=3, help='number of residual blocks in the local enhancer network')
        self.parser.add_argument('--n_local_enhancers', type=int, default=1, help='number of local enhancers to use')        
        self.parser.add_argument('--niter_fix_global', type=int, default=0, help='number of epochs that we only train the outmost local enhancer')        

        # for instance-wise features
        self.parser.add_argument('--no_instance', action='store_false',  help='if specified, do *not* add instance map as input')        
        self.parser.add_argument('--instance_feat', action='store_true', help='if specified, add encoded instance features as input')
        self.parser.add_argument('--label_feat', action='store_true', help='if specified, add encoded label features as input')        
        self.parser.add_argument('--feat_num', type=int, default=3, help='vector length for encoded features')        
        self.parser.add_argument('--load_features', action='store_true', help='if specified, load precomputed feature maps')
        self.parser.add_argument('--n_downsample_E', type=int, default=4, help='# of downsampling layers in encoder') 
        self.parser.add_argument('--nef', type=int, default=16, help='# of encoder filters in the first conv layer')        
        self.parser.add_argument('--n_clusters', type=int, default=10, help='number of clusters for features')        

        self.initialized = True

    def parse(self, save=True):
        if not self.initialized:
            self.initialize()
        self.opt = self.parser.parse_args()
        self.opt.isTrain = self.isTrain   # train or test

        str_ids = self.opt.gpu_ids.split(',')
        self.opt.gpu_ids = []
        for str_id in str_ids:
            id = int(str_id)
            if id >= 0:
                self.opt.gpu_ids.append(id)
        
        # set gpu ids
        if len(self.opt.gpu_ids) > 0:
            torch.cuda.set_device(self.opt.gpu_ids[0])

        args = vars(self.opt)

        print('------------ Options -------------')
        for k, v in sorted(args.items()):
            print('%s: %s' % (str(k), str(v)))
        print('-------------- End ----------------')

        # save to the disk        
        expr_dir = os.path.join(self.opt.checkpoints_dir, self.opt.name)
        util.mkdirs(expr_dir)
        if save and not self.opt.continue_train:
            file_name = os.path.join(expr_dir, 'opt.txt')
            with open(file_name, 'wt') as opt_file:
                opt_file.write('------------ Options -------------\n')
                for k, v in sorted(args.items()):
                    opt_file.write('%s: %s\n' % (str(k), str(v)))
                opt_file.write('-------------- End ----------------\n')
        return self.opt
```